# What's proper JS syntax for deleting a record from a web database?

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I use the following to display, with innerHTML, the Javascript-based webSQL data (containing 4 fields) on the HTML page:

```
var rowid = results.rows.item(i).id;
document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML += "<table><tr><td><index type='button' class='buttonDel' onclick='delRecord(\"" + rowid + "\")' value='Delete'>" + results.rows.item(i).id + "</td><td>" + results.rows.item(i).data1 + "</td><td>" + results.rows.item(i).data2 + "</td><td>" + results.rows.item(i).data3 + "</td></tr></table>";
```

A red Delete button appears in the ID column of the HTML table with the correct id put into var rowid (confirmed with an alert). The button calls the following functions to delete the record. Of course, that doesn't happen.

```
// Delete a row in the DB

function delRecord(rowid) {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "DEMO", 2000000);
    db.transaction(delDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
function delDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("DELETE from DEMO WHERE id == rowid"); 
}
```

What is the correct syntax to delete the record?

Here's how the buttons are being formatted:

```
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("Returned rows = " + results.rows.length);
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
var rowid = results.rows.item(i).id;
                document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML += 
    "<table><tr><td><index type='button' class='buttonDel' onclick='delRecord(\"" + 
    rowid + "\")' value='Delete'>" + 
        results.rows.item(i).id + 
        "</td><td>" + results.rows.item(i).data1 + 
        "</td><td>" + results.rows.item(i).data2 + 
        "</td><td>" + results.rows.item(i).data3 + "</td></tr></table>";
                }
```

Comment: I think it should be "=" instead of "=="

Comment: No, the record remains. Isn't that the assignment operator and not the equal? I see that no error is being generated.

Comment: @Steve: SQL has a different syntax than programming languages ;)

Comment: @FelixKling WebSQL uses JavaScript, though :)

Comment: Well, = does not work either, so something else is wrong.

Comment: When asking questions, *isolate* the actual problem. In this case it should only be the "execute bit", preferably in a small jsfiddle test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is [`DELETE FROM tableName [WHERE expr]`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) (The underlying implementations all use SQLite, AFAIK.)

However, there are several related problems:

1. The condition used is wrong, SQL uses `=` for equality.
2. `rowid`, as string content, is wrong. That will never be the ID because no "magic replacement" is done. Instead, use a parameterized query and specify the bound value.

Consider:

```
function deleteRecord(rowid) {
    var db = getCurrentDatabase();
    db.transaction(
      function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM demo WHERE id = ?", [rowid]); 
      });
}
```

I also used a closure to make `rowid` readily accessible. Refer to some [tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm) for more general and examples.

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that I was used to PHP/MySQL, but once I attempted webSQL with JavaScript, I felt out of my depth. Wasn't sure there should be callbacks or something as part of the syntax.

Comment: Using your example, I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: getCurrentDatabase is not defined" When researching this, a search for "getCurrentDatabase" showed no results. I also tried: var db = DB_NAME ( [Database] );

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. Thanks! This is solved.

Comment: @Steve Just a placeholder function to open/obtain the DB :)